# How to populate scene with randomly posed characters with armatures?

Tags: modifiers, rigging

I have a collection with differently posed characters, I want to populate the scene with a lot of these characters. Is there a way to do this without placing them by hand on the floor? I know you can use the particle system to populate a scene with objects (e.g. trees to create a random generated forest) but I don't think it works with rigged characters, it only seems to use either the armature or a random piece of the character itself. Thanks.

Comment: and it also works with geometry nodes, if you wanna use that

Comment: Either the armature or a random piece of the character itself? Well, first of all you don't need to instantiate the armature, only the character. But if a character consists of several separate meshes this will be a problem. You can instantiate a single object or a collection of objects... but then each object will be used separately no matter if it beleongs to a certain character - or you have to enable _Whole Collection_. Only in this case all characters will be instantiated together.

Answer (score 1):

Particles do work with rigged characters:

[image]